# Sum function not displying sum in proper way in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I want a sum of attribute values where XX present in attribute code.and I want to group these sum on the basis of country.

```
ATTRIBUTE_CODE ATTRIBUTE_VALUE Country
XX                1               ALB
SP                1               ALB
XX                1               ALB
TT                0               ALB
PQ                0               ALB
XX                2               AND
EM               28001            AND
SP                6               AND
XX                1               AND
....             .....            ...
```

I tried below code

```
r=df[df['ATTRIBUTE_CODE']=='XX'].groupby('Country')['ATTRIBUTE_VALUE'].sum()
```

but it is giving me output like

```
ALB                                                   11
AND    2111122221222211111111211222222441122221111112...
AUT    2121111112221122421222121122211111221112122211...
BEL    1422211211214112112222111121228112114414222461...
BGR    1312111121112212211121111211131121211221221621...
```

Comment: Your `attribute_value` is a string- `sum`'ming Strings gives you a bigger string. Convert it to a number first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried [groupby with aggregate](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html)?

```
r = df.groupby(['Country', 'ATTRIBUTE_CODE']).agg({'ATTRIBUTE_VALUE': 'sum'})
print(r)
```

```
                        ATTRIBUTE_VALUE
Country ATTRIBUTE_CODE
ALB     PQ                            0
        SP                            1
        TT                            0
        XX                            2
AND     EM                        28001
        SP                            6
        XX                            3
```